# Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Tags: contest-math

How many numbers do there exist having 2013 digits, in which every two-digit number composed of two consecutive digits is a multiple of either 17 or 23? (Taken from Singapore and Asian Schools Math Olympiad)

Comment: Have you made a list of all two-digit numbers that are multiples of 17 or 23?  Which pairs of these can form consecutive pairs, overlapping as required by the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Allowable pairs of consecutive digits are $17, 23, 34, 46, 51, 68, 69, 85, 92, 00$.  Since the second number in each pair must be the first number of a new pair, the digits, $1, 5, 7, 8$ quickly lead to dead ends.

This leaves us with a cycle $\overline{23469}$.  Starting where you wish in this cycle gives $5$ possibilities.  You probably would not count the sequence of $2013$ zeros, as a $2013$-digit number

---

Thanks to hardmath for seeing where to get four more sequences: You get extra solutions by attaching some of the 'dead end' strings at the very end.  So you can get four additional solutions ending in 68; 685; 6851; 68517.  I think these sequences would start respectively with 4; 6; 9; 2.

Comment: Thanks! But the answer states 9 possibilities.

Comment: Interesting, but  if I understand the problem correctly, I am not seeing where any other possibilities would come from.  Of course I could be missing something.

Comment: Just trying to comprehend this problem. I thought in 46, 4 and 6 are not consecutive numbers as in the case 23 or 34.

Comment: I understood consecutive digits to be adjacent digits in the sequence, not consecutive in the sense of ordering the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: Ok. Trying to figure out the 9 possibilities.

Comment: Some additional solutions arise because when we near the end of the required 2013 digits, we can depart from the repetition of $\overline{23469}$.  For example, instead of $69$ we could put $68$, and either end there or add further $85$ and end there, or add further $51$ and end there, or add further $17$.  These four extra possibilities plus the five already identified make 9 solutions.

Comment: @hardmath: Very nice!

Comment: @paw88789: Feel free to edit into your Answer!

Comment: @hardmath:  I did edit your idea into the post.  Thanks!

Comment: @hardmath Many thanks! 17 can only come right at the end of the string

Comment: @pirsquare:  Indeed all the solutions can be strung together with the least significant digits $17$, and you can snip the nine distinct solutions of length $2013$ out of that "master path".

Comment: @hardmath Absolutely!